# php get dom html elements

Tags: php, html

I have some PHP code which returns the HTML content from another file:

```
$html = file_get_contents('myFile.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

This is a part of the content of $html:

```
<table class="content_table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Value1</td>
         <td>Value2</td>
         <td>Value3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Value1</td>
         <td>Value2</td>
         <td>Value3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>                                               
</table>
```

My question:
How can I get all the values of `<td>` where the table tag has the class "content_table"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query looks for `table` element that has `content_table` class, then extracts the `td` values from it:

```
<?php

$html = '<table class="content_table">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>Value2</td>
      <td>Value3</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>                                               
</table>';
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$data = [];
foreach($xpath->query('//table[@class="content_table"]') as $table) {
    foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('td') as $td) {
        $data[] = $td->nodeValue;
    }
}

print_r($data);
```

Or if you need only `td` elements that have `content_table` class then it do the task:

```
foreach($xpath->query('//td[@class="content_table"]') as $td) {
    $data[] = $td->nodeValue;
}
```

***Example html:***

```
$html = '<table class="content_table">
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td class="content_table">Value2</td>
      <td>Value3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td class="content_table">Value2</td>
      <td>Value3</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>                                               
</table>';
```

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you very much :)